# How to make an axes current which is inside a figure created by GUIDE?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I created a bank figure using GUIDE and put an axes object inside it and saved the figure. Now I want to load the figure and set its axes as current axes object. This is my code:

```
close all; clear all; clc;
fh = openfig('test.fig');
ah = findobj(fh, 'tag', 'axes1');
figure(fh);
axes(ah);
plot(rand(10, 1));
```

But `plot` creates a new figure and plots in it! Am I missing something?

I know that I can solve it with `plot(ah, ...)`, but I want to make `gca` to return this new axes. I have a lot of plotting codes that I want to be drawn in this new axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `HandleVisibility` of GUIDE figures is set such that they aren't automatically detected. For example  if you load the figure and then call `gcf`, you'll also create a new figure.

To have the plot be placed within the axes, you can specify the axes *explicitly* as the parent of the `plot` command.

```
plot(rand(10, 1), 'Parent', ah)
```

Alternately, you could specify that the `HandleVisibility` of the figure is `'on'`. And then plot will be able to find it. This could be done by either setting the value of `HandleVisibility` using the property editor in GUIDE or calling the `set` function:

```
set(fh, 'HandleVisibility', 'on')
```

I recommend the first option as explicitly specifying the parent axes is always better than implicit.